# Deserialize JSON With Only Canonical Type String Using Jackson

Tags: java, jackson

I have a JSON string

```
{
    "type": "com.example.model.Person",
    "data": {
        "firstName": "Bob",
        ...
    }
}
```

That is represented by the following class.

```
public class Container<T> {
    private String type;
    private T data;

    // Getters and Setters
}
```

(I've even tried just removing the generic type and replacing it with `Object`.)

I have tried the following:

- `new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, Class.forName(canonical))`
- `new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, TypeFactory.defaultInstance().constructFromCanonical(canonical))`

I need to be able to deserialize the JSON string into a `Container<T>` instance with only the given canonical type string. How can this be done?

Comment: If you're trusting the `type` field, use `@JsonTypeInfo(use=CLASS, property="type")`, and prefer an abstract `NAME` such as just `Person` for flexibility.

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- I've used these mechanisms in the past for polymorphic types but not generic types. Assuming you do not have to register all subtypes this may work. If you have the time to create a complete answer that would be great. I am not seeing exactly how to put the pieces together.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same example and its working for me

[image]

Is it the same you are looking for  or something else

Comment: Not quite the same. You're using `Container.class` to tell jackson what type you want the string deserialized too. You're only allowed to use the value in the `type` property: `com.example.model.Person`. Of course assuming you also have a Person class derived.

Comment: May be  TypeReference would help in this case
Person<Object> c =  mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<Person<Object>>() {});